# Getting Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null Custom Filter for search in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using custom filter for my table content search my custom filter function is

```
return function(data, search) {
    if(angular.isDefined(search)) {
      var results = [];
      var i;

      var searchVal = $filter('lowercase')(search);
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var name = $filter('lowercase')(data[i].name);
        var description = $filter('lowercase')(data[i].description);
        if(name.indexOf(searchVal) > -1 || description.indexOf(searchVal) > -1){
          results.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      return results;
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  };
```

when i put any text in search box it will get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
```

Comment: It probably says that either your name or description is null so you cannot call indexOf method from a null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((name !=null && name.indexOf(searchVal) > -1) || (description!=null && description.indexOf(searchVal) > -1)){
          results.push(data[i]);
    }
```

name  or description is giving null value try above code

Answer (score 0):

Check null condition

```
return function(data, search) {
if(angular.isDefined(search)) {
  var results = [];
  var i;

  var searchVal = $filter('lowercase')(search);
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var name = $filter('lowercase')(data[i].name);
    var description = $filter('lowercase')(data[i].description);
    if(name !== null &&  description !== null){
     if(name.indexOf(searchVal) > -1 || description.indexOf(searchVal) > -1){
      results.push(data[i]);
     }
    }
  }
  return results;
} else {
  return data;
}
};
```